# Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

This is not a duplicate. I've only found one other question that addresses this issue which still hasn't been answered.

Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. I've copied this code directly from the Angular docs and put it into a new component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive-favorite-color',
  template: `
  Favorite Color: <input type="text" [formControl]="favoriteColorControl">
`
})
export class FavoriteColorComponent {
  favoriteColorControl = new FormControl('');
}
```

Here is my module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FavoriteColorComponent } from './favorite-color/favorite-color.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FavoriteColorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I added

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

to the module to try and fix this issue. The specific problem is the line `[formControl]="favoriteColorControl"`. I guess the HTML tag `input` doesn't know what `[formControl]` is.

Also this isn't an issue with my VS code. I've tried going into the command pallete and restarting the Angular Language server as well as restarting VS code.